# How to fix `Cannot find module ./logging/Logger` in Webpack-cli

Tags: node.js, jenkins, logging, webpack

When i tried webpack build using webpack-cli by jenkins, following error comes up.

I already tried yarn upgrade, global added webpack-cli..
but nothing happens.

Following code is got by jenkins.
    /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                    throw err;
                    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module './logging/Logger'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/webpack/lib/Stats.js:12:21)
    at Module._compile (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:30:15)
    at Module._compile (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:20:21)
    at Module._compile (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/websdk (develop)/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: This is cause of .lock file. closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use npm install webpack in terminal and try